# Expected value of a transformed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable and let $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel-measurable function. I know that:
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f_X(x) \ dx$$
(If $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$ exitsts).
I know how to prove this when $g\in C^1$ and monotone(at least it must satisfy these restriction on the support of $X$), but I don't know how to prove this in the more general setting. Could you help me?

Comment: I haven't worked all the way through, but I suspect it will help to look at the sets of $x$ where $g(x)$ has similar values. $$I(a,b) = \int_{g^{-1}([a,b])} g(x) f_X(x)\, dx$$

Comment: If $g$ is only Borel measurable and can take positive and negative values do we know that any of the two sides of the equation is well defined ?

Comment: Check out the change of variables formula on the Wikipedia page for pushforward measure: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

Comment: It gives a reference to a proof of the theorem.

Comment: @zxmkn Thank you! :)

Comment: The more general setting follows from measure-theoretic results. Essentially you write, for $g \geq 0,$ $g = \lim g_n$ where the $g_n$ are simple functions (linear combinations of indicators of measurable sets) and the limit is monotone. By monotone convergence theorem, it will suffice to show the theorem for each $g_n$ and by linearity of the integral suffices to show for indicator functions. The result then becomes trivial.